# How to have a private upload and download system in drupal?

Tags: file, drupal, upload, download, private

Lets say Mark uploads a file using a content type. I only want his friend Steve to have the access to download that file. Rest of the users dont even know if it was uploaded. How can i do this in Drupal? any module available? any triggers?? rules? How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul:

I have never done it but I did find a useful post for you http://ygerasimov.com/drupal7-upload-private-file-easy

It does what you have asked if you using d7 if you are using d6 then there is a module called private upload